remotes::install_local() still tries to get remote repositories
I have two packages, packageone and packagetwo. packagetwo imports packageone and lists the repo URL in the DESCRIPTION:
Remotes:
    git::http://url/to/packageone.git

I am working with a colleague that does not have access to the packageone and packagetwo repositories (company policy), so my bright idea was to zip up the repositories and hand them off for my colleague to install via remotes::install_local():
remotes::install_local("path/to/packageone", upgrade = "never")
remotes::install_local("path/to/packagetwo", upgrade = "never")

But they get an error because remotes::install_local() is still trying to access the repo URL, even though packageone is already installed.
Error: Failed to install 'packagetwo' from local:
  Command failed (128)
In addition: Warning message:
In system(full, intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = quiet) :
  running command ''/usr/bin/git' ls-remote http://url/to/packageone.git  2>/dev/null' had status 128 and error message 'Function not implemented'

How can I tell remotes::install_local() to ignore the URLs specified in DESCRIPTION Remotes section? Note that packagetwo also has CRAN dependencies, so I'd like to still install those.
EDIT: Apparently, this behavior is intentional: https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/815

Just a workaround, but you could try unzipping, then from repo library(devtools); check(); build_readme(); document(); install(). Edit DESCRIPTION as necessary beforehand.

Already tried R CMD INSTALL /path/to/usb/your_package.zip on the command line?

Current workaround is to first install all the dependencies other than packageone:
install.packages(stringr::str_subset(remotes::local_package_deps("path/to/packagetwo"), "packageone", negate = TRUE))
remotes::install_local("path/to/packagetwo", dependencies = FALSE)

But I'm hoping there is a more streamlined solution.
